# How to get value inside a PHP object array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON

```
{
    "code": "1",
    "message": "User Created",
    "data": {
        "name": "Customer Name",
        "email": "customer@email.com"
    }
}
```

How do I get the name and email here using PHP?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kita

$variable["data"]["email"]
$variable["data"][0]->email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json_str = '{
    "code": "1",
    "message": "User Created",
    "data": {
        "name": "Customer Name",
        "email": "customer@email.com"
    }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json_str, true);
echo $arr['data']['name'];
echo $arr['data']['email'];
```

Comment: Might want to use $array instead of $obj to avoid confusion since you made an associative array with the second argument to json_decode set to true.

Comment: @Devon good point thanks, i'll update the code